# VB.NET College Homework

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub cmdmark_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdmark.Click
    Dim intsum As Integer, intnum As Integer
    Dim inthighest As Integer
    Dim intlowest As Integer
    intnum = InputBox("Enter the mark")
    intsum = intnum + intsum
    intnum = InputBox("Enter the mark For subject 2")
    intsum = intnum + intsum
    intnum = InputBox("Enter the mark for subject 3")
    intsum = intnum + intsum

    Lbltotal.Text = "Total marks are" & intsum
    lblaverage.Text = "The average is" & intsum / 3

    If intnum > intlowest Then
        intlowest = intsum
    End If
    If intsum > inthighest Then
        inthighest = intsum

        Lbllowest.Text = "The lowest number is" & intnum
        Lblhighest.Text = "The highets number is" & intnum
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Basically when i add my three marks in it does work but it doesn't show the lowest mark but instead it shows the same as mark as highest

Comment: Check the variable name used to display the output and used in the comparison and set the labels after the last if block

Comment: In the future, please use titles which describe the problem, and ask an actual question.  See [Ask]

Comment: And to be brutally honest here, this isn't really a homework help site either

Answer (score 1):

```
Lbllowest.Text = "The lowest number is" & intnum
```

and

```
Lblhighest.Text = "The highets number is" & intnum
```

Are the same integer, is 1 reason it's showing the same value.

maybe try using 3 separate Integers, Mark1_Integer, Mark2_Integer, Mark3_Integer. It will be easier for you to find your high and low.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the lowest and highest values after each input:

```
intnum = InputBox("Enter the mark")
intsum = intsum
intlowest = intsum
inthighest = intsum
intnum = InputBox("Enter the mark For subject 2")
intsum = intnum + intsum
If intnum < intlowest Then
    intlowest = intnum 
End If
If intsum > inthighest Then
    inthighest = intnum 
End If
intnum = InputBox("Enter the mark for subject 3")
intsum = intnum + intsum
If intnum < intlowest Then
    intlowest = intnum 
End If
If intsum > inthighest Then
    inthighest = intnum 
End If

Lbllowest.Text = "The lowest number is" & intlowest 
Lblhighest.Text = "The highets number is" & inthighest
```

There is still much that can be improved in this code, like changing implicit casting to explicit casting and refactor the code repeats into a method, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge of Python but I think you could have tried

```
 If intnum >= intlowest Then
    intlowest = intsum
```

or

```
 If intnum == intlowest Then
    intlowest = intsum
```

But actually what I learned from [ace writers](http://acewriters.org/write-my-thesis.html) is that you should always test it and test it, try different combinations till it works.